# Using the razor_imu_9dof package with the sparkfun IMU (14001)

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just wondering if anyone has had any success getting the new version of the [Sparkfun 9DoF Razor IMU M0 Board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14001) working with the [razor_imu_9dof](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof) node? I've been trying to get this working for a while now and although I've made some progress it's not quite working properly.

The firmware provided in the ROS package only supports the old (now discontinued) versions of the board, so I hunted around for any ports to the newer version, I've managed to find [this repository](https://github.com/lebarsfa/razor-9dof-ahrs) by user [lebarsfa](https://github.com/lebarsfa) that works with the new version of the board (as well as the older ones).

However using the board I've got and this firmware the sensor orientation is not being correctly calculated, sometimes the firmware outputs nothing but NAN values and at other times they're real numbers but drifting wildly. This if after going through the calibration procedure.

Has anyone managed to get the new 14001 board working properly?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276885/using-the-razor_imu_9dof-package-with-the-sparkfun-imu-(14001)/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A solution I found that helped fix the reporting of NaN values was to change the DMP_SAMPLE_RATE value in the Arduino code, under the Sensors.ino file from 100 to 50. It became much more stable and have not seen NaN values being printed out on the serial monitor. I'm not sure on the reason why this would fix it, but it worked after I tinkered around with the code.

---

Originally posted by [freelancer22](https://answers.ros.org/users/32838/freelancer22/) with karma: 26 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-12-02**:
Thanks, I'll give this a go on Monday ane let you know how it goes.